# Rails 3.1: CSS updates don't reflect in website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, assets

I have an app written in Rails 3.1 and I need completely to change the CSS styles in the project. I bought a template, deleted the current CSS styles from `assets/stylesheets` (including `application.css`) and pushed there the new CSS files.

Further I modified the `stylesheet_link_tag` with the names of new CSS files.

Then, when I open browser with the app, refresh the app - there are not loaded the new files. When I take a look at the generated source code, there are still the paths to the old CSS files.

I have read that probably would help me `rake assets:precompile` - but this is kind of impractical to every time, when I make a change in CSS files to run this command (which takes like 2 minutes I guess).

Is there any better way to handle it?

Thank you

**EDIT: ** In the `<head>` tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Do you have a new `application.css` in your template? Or did you end up without one?

Comment: No, I deleted it from the `assets/stylesheets`.

Answer (score 0):

- Could it be just a browser cache? Try to force the reload (ctrl+f5).
- Try to delete `<your_app>/tmp/cache` and restart the server.

Comment: No, this is not an cache issue, I've tried it before. I believe it has something to do with the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you decide to switch off the asset pipeline (which I don't recommend because it's actually pretty good), you're going to have to build yourself a new `application.css`. If you don't to that, your CSS files won't be recognized at all.

Just think of it as an inventory of every one of your CSS files. You can use this as a template.

```
/*
 *= require cssfile1
 *= require cssfile2
 */
```

And then, revert the stylesheet link tag to its original form in your layout. Inside your `application.html.erb', remove any reference to your CSS files and use this instead:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Yup, importing new asset files into a rails application isn't a straightforward proposition.

Comment: Thanks mdepolli for your answer. I did it, I created the new `application.css`, I put there all new CSS files (without .`css` extension) and refreshed the page - and still the same. What do you think please about the `revert the stylesheet link tag to its original form in your layout`?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that info.

Comment: Yea, this is what I have in my `<head>` tags, but still the same - cannot display the current content of new CSS files. Still the old ones.

Comment: I also tried to delete `public/assets` folder, but it didn't help me. When I display the source code of the website, there are still the same files.

Comment: Wait, you say you keep seeing the content of the old CSS you deleted?

Comment: When I display the source code of my website, I see there the paths to  the old CSS files which I deleted. I don't understand why. When I click on the file displayed in the source code, I get an error about missing file (because I deleted it).

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `<head>`section of your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`?

Comment: Ok, so I just ran the `rake assets:precompile RAILS_development`, but in the source code are still the old paths to files... quandary.

Comment: Did you try restarting your local rails server (Webrick, I imagine)?

Comment: Yea, like a million times... I just tried to remove the `<%= 
      stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>` from the application layout and despite that are the load styles loaded...

Comment: It's really weird that you're seeing files you already deleted. It makes me think it could be a browser issue after all. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.